# laravel 7: how to display data with if / case statements in the raw / query builder

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-7

I want to add a new field called status to the select query, where the condition of the field is the result of a select query using a case / if statement.

This is my table now:

| fullname | is_active |
| --- | --- |
| Mr. X | false |
| Mr. Z | true |

the expectations I want after the query:

| fullname | is_active | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mr. X | false | Yes |
| Mr. Z | true | No |

This is my code, but still displays an error:
`Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "0" does not exist LINE 2: WHEN app.is_active = "0" THEN "Yes"`

```
$data = DB::table('my_table as app')
   ->select('fullname','is_active',
             DB::raw('(CASE 
                WHEN app.is_active = "0" THEN "Yes" 
                ELSE "No" 
                END) AS status'))
   ->get();
```

Thakns a lot.

Comment: What is the logic behind the computed `status` column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry, I just changed my post by adding my code

Comment: Does your actual code really not have a comma after `'is_active'` ?

Comment: Sorry there is a typo there, this is just a sample code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using single quotes for MySQL string literals:

```php
$data = DB::table('my_table as app')
    ->select('fullname', 'is_active',
             DB::raw("CASE app.is_active WHEN '0' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS status"))
    ->get();
```

If the above fixes your problem, then I would actually be a bit surprised, because MySQL usually will accept double quotes for string literals.  The error message you see implies that `"0"` is being interpreted as a column name instead.